# Web service code to add SQL string connection and string query manually?

Tags: sql, vb.net, web-services

I'm using the Web service as given below for getting the data from database. In that code it has static string connection and string query. I'm using the same web service for multiple functions. Instead of using the same function I need to give the string query and string connection manually to avoid multiple of using the same code. Is it possible to give the string connection and string query in run time.

Here is the code.

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetData() As String

    Dim sqlcon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim sqlcmd, cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand
    Dim objeDS, objeDS1 As DataSet
    Dim adpp, adpp1 As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim dt, dt1 As DataTable

    Dim pack_tbl As New DataTable

    sqlcon.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("constr")
    sqlcon.Open()

    sqlcmd = New SqlClient.SqlCommand()
    sqlcmd.Connection = sqlcon
    sqlcmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    sqlcmd.CommandText = "sqlcommand"
    objeDS = New DataSet()
    adpp = New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter()
    adpp.SelectCommand = sqlcmd

    adpp.Fill(objeDS)
    sqlcon.Close()
    dt = New DataTable()
    dt = objeDS.Tables(0)
    Return objeDS.GetXml()
    'Return "Welcome"

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code this helps you.

**VB code**

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetData(ByVal strQuery As String, ByVal strCon As String) As String
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    dt.Clear()
    Using conn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(strCon).ConnectionString
        Using cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = strQuery
            cmd.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            da.Fill(dt)
            Dim serializer As New System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer()
            Dim rows As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))()
            Dim row As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
            For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
                row = New Dictionary(Of String, Object)()
                For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                    row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr(col))
                Next
                rows.Add(row)
            Next
            Return serializer.Serialize(rows)
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```